# Best way to add info/description to my items?

Tags: sql, json, database

I made a geo game a while back where the player has to guess an item from an image (what I call an item is a SQL row basically) for example the bot sends the flag of the Netherlands, you have to type "Netherlands" to win.

Items can be the flag of a country, a capital city, a french department...

I made an info tab where it would basically give info about an item (ie region, former name, capital city, etc).

What I would like to do is properly save this information. I don't really know if I should store this in files like JSON because I would also like to give stats (Win rate per region, amount of games played per region, etc...).

Also, these elements are not fixed because some items have regions, capital cities or whatever and some don't.

Item examples :

(For a flag

| Column | Attribute |
| --- | --- |
| ID | 1 |
| Name | United Kingdom |
| Former name | United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland |
| Code | GB |
| Continent | Europe |
| Subregion | Northern Europe |
| Capital city | London |

...

(For a U.S. State)

| Column | Attribute |
| --- | --- |
| ID | 1 |
| Name | Arizona |
| Capital city | Phoenix |
| Largest city | Phoenix |

...

Comment: you can add as may columns as you need even if they are empty (so 2000 or so are possible). also you can always change the design, which takes a bit of programming to convert.

Comment: Oh alright so it's not a bad way of doing it ? This is pretty much what I have now already but I planned on adding more info for each items. Hence I was not too sure about this way.

Comment: json isn't a good format to manipulate, as it takes some learning, to do that ion sql and most databases have not that much json functions anyway, so if you dsve the data in coulmns you can easy access them and query them

Comment: alright then I'll just keep my db and add colums. Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

The both solution (Add all as column and json) are not the proper way.

I think the best design is to have a key-value table.

```
Create Table tableName (ID INT, [Key] SYSNAME, [Value])
```

And data will look like:

| ID | Key | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Name | Arizona |
| 1 | Capital City | Phoenix |
| 1 | Largest City | Phoenix |
| 2 | Name | United Kingdom |
| 2 | Former name | United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland |

Most valuable benefits: No Extra storage for columns with large amount of rows with `NULL` value.

Comment: I kinda did it this way when I tried to upgrade my db but it was a bit more messy. One question, would you add a FK "gamemode_id" references gamemodes (ID) as a new attribute ? ie tableName (ID, gamemode_id, Key, Value) ? thanks